# Ternary operators and Return in C

Tags: c, conditional-operator

Why can't we use return keyword inside ternary operators  in C, like this:

```
sum > 0 ? return 1 : return 0;
```

Comment: What's wrong with `return sum > 0 ? 1 : 0;`?

Comment: Or, for that matter, `if (sum > 0) return 1 ; else return 0 ;`

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. There is nothing wrong with return sum > 0 ? 1 : 0; I just want to know why can't we use it in the way mentioned above in the question.

Comment: Or for that matter `return sum > 0;` ?

Comment: Because `a ? b : c` is an expression that contains expressions, not statements. And `return d` is a statement, not an expression.

Comment: Because it is an operator, not an `if` statement.

Comment: If you want to return `1` for true and `0` for false, you can just do `return condition;`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`return` is a statement. Statements cannot be used inside expressions in that manner.

Answer (score 36):

Because a ternary operation is an expression and you can't use statements in expresssions.

You can easily use a ternary operator in a return though.

```
return sum > 0 ? 1 : 0;
```

Or as DrDipShit pointed out:

```
return sum > 0;
```

Comment: of just: return sum > 0; which works out as returning 1 or 0 anyway.

Comment: @DrDipShit: very true, in this case that works just as well :)

Answer (score 15):

The ternary operator deals in expressions, but `return` is a statement.

The syntax of the `return` statement is

`return` *expr* `;`

The syntax of the ternary conditional operator is

*expr1* `?` *expr2* `:` *expr3*

So you can plug in an invocation of the ternary operator as the *expr* in a `return` statement.  But you cannot plug in a `return` statement as *expr2* or *expr3* of a ternary operator.

The ternary expression acts a lot like an `if` statement, but it is not an exact replacement for an `if` statement.  If you want to write

```
if(sum > 0)
     return 1;
else return 0;
```

you can write it as a true `if` statement, but you can't convert it to using `? :` without rearranging it a little, as we've seen here.

Answer (score 9):

Because `return` is a statement, not an expression. You can't do `int a = return 1;` either.

Answer (score 2):

See the syntax of a ternary operator is

```
expr1 ? expr2: expr3;
```

where `expr1`, `expr2`, `expr3` are expressions;

The operator `?:` works as follows 
`expr1` is evaluated first  if it is true `expr2` is evaluated otherwise `expr3` is evaluated.

hence in expressions the **return** statement can not be used in C-language.

Answer (score 2):

The `return` statement is used for returning from a `function`, you can't use inside ternary operator.

```
 (1==1)? return 1 : return 0; /* can't use return inside ternary operator */
```

you can make it like

```
return (1==1) ? 1 : 0;
```

The syntax of a ternary operator follows as

```
expr1 ? expr2 : expr3;
```

where `expr1`, `expr2`, `expr3` are expressions and `return` is a statement, not an expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can use gcc's/clang's statement expressions feature.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define discard(value) ({return value; value;})

int foo(int a) {
        int b = a%2 ?: discard(0);
        return b*a;
}

int main(int argc, char argv) {
        printf("foo(%d) = %d;\n", argc, foo(argc));
        return foo(argc);
}
```

Results are:

```
$ ./bar 
foo(1) = 1;
$ ./bar 2
foo(2) = 0;
$ ./bar 2 3
foo(3) = 3;
$ ./bar 2 3 4
foo(4) = 0;
$ ./bar 2 3 4 5
foo(5) = 5;
$ ./bar 2 3 4 5 6
foo(6) = 0;
$ ./bar 2 3 4 5 6 7
foo(7) = 7;
$ ./bar 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
foo(8) = 0;
$ ./bar 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
foo(9) = 9;
$ ./bar 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
foo(10) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just by looking at the syntax you should know that an statement cannot be used in an expression. 
What you want can be achived by doing:`return sum > 0 ? 1 : 0;`