# C ternary-If without returning value

Tags: c

I just started learning the C prog. language after using Java for a while.

I'm currently trying to use the ternary If in the following way:

> (currIndex == 0) ? return 1:currIndex--;

I know this *isn't*  the traditional assignment form:

> **max =**  (a > b)?a:b

Is what I'm trying to do possible? if not, what's the reason?

(My motive here is keeping the code short as this line will appear many times in a switch-case expression)

Thanks a million.

Comment: In the first example, you *do* return something from the function later? Oh, and as a general tip, please try to avoid using the ternary expression in that way, it will make your code harder to read.

Comment: Try it; you should be able to figure.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: yes, I return 0 anyhow.
You're right (second part), but it's nested in a long switch-case expression and appears many times.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566413/ternary-operators-and-return-in-c)

Comment: Why not: `if (currIndex == 0) return 1; currindex--;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, this code from the question will not compile:

```
(currIndex == 0) ? return 1 : currIndex--;
```

The `return` statement is not an expression that can be embedded into the ternary operator like that.

You could write:

```
return (currIndex == 0) ? 1 : currIndex--;
```

though the decrement only makes any sense if `currIndex` is a global variable (defined outside a function; it might be local to the file or global to the whole program).

Comment: That's starting to make sense. The problem is that this validation is only one of many. I guess I'll have to put it in its own function.

Comment: Not a good way to return when you have increment/decrement operation on same line. Always return 'currIndex-1' or 'currIndex' as is (as needed), but never with increment/decrement operator as the behavior may be unpredictable.

Comment: This code will `return` even if `currIndex` is not 0. I don;t think that's the intended result.

Comment: If the code is not intended to return when `currIndex` is not 0, then the conditional needs to be: `if (currIndex == 0) return 1; currIndex--;` which is a regular `if` with `return` and a plain decrement.

Answer (score 3):

If, as you say, you return a value anyway, then yes that's not going to be a problem, besides the problem that you actually can't do it that way (`return` is not allowed there). To solve it, *and* make the code easier to follow, you can do this instead:

```
if (curindex == 0)
    return 1;

--curindex;

/* Rest of code */
```

There's no need for an `else` in this case, as the `else` part is the decrement *and* the rest of the code, which you won't do if you `return` from the function.

Comment: I'm getting a "error: expected expression before 'return'" when entering the line: 
(currIndex == 0) ? return 1:currIndex--;

Comment: @user2190298, return has to be the leftmost keyword in your ternary operator. Return CANNOT occur in-between your ternary operation!

Comment: @Pankaj so a regular If is needed if I want to return on condition?

Comment: @user2190298, Yes, you need to use 'If' if you need to return only if the condition is successful, else want to continue with the current function

Comment: @user2190298, Joachim's answer is a better one and more appropriate to your needs. (If i understood your requirement properly) :)

Comment: @Pankaj Maybe the solution is better in my answer, but the first sentence is wrong. :) Updated it now though.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, Oh! just noticed the edit :) actually i just saw the code and the last sentence (no need for 'else'), didn't pay attn. to the first part.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you use ternary operator here? `currIndex` seems to be a local variable, you won't lose anything if you decrement it even when you return:

```
if (!currIndex--)
    return 1;
```