# C – How to use an exit/return statement in ternary operator?

Tags: c, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

I wanted to formulate these two if statements in a shorter way:

```
//FUNCTION PROTOTYPES
int checkCommandLineArguments(int argc, char *argv[]);
int checkFile(char *argv[]);

//MAIN FUNCTIONxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    checkCommandLineArguments(argc, &argv[1]);
    checkFile(&argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
//xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx



//F1–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
int checkCommandLineArguments(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover image\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
//–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

//F2–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
int checkFile(char *argv[])
{
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (NULL == file)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
//–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
```

I thought about using a ternary operator:

```
(argc != 2) ? printf("Error X\n"), exit(1) : (NULL == file) ? printf("Cannot open file!\n"),
        exit(1): return 0 ;
```

However, it doesn't seem to work (probably because of the return/exit statements). How can I fix that, or are there any other (more appropriate) ways to do this?

Thank you!

**EDIT 1**
It has been commented that ternary operators don't work with statements, so that option is off the table.
However, I'm still searching for better ways to do this.

**EDIT 2**
I added a more extended code example, since it has been asked for in the comments.

Comment: It's best not to try to cram hard-to-read code onto a single line. One way to do it is to make your own `myexit(char *reason)` function, and then you can shorten the code to, say, `if (NULL == file) myexit("Cannot open file!");` (on two lines).

Comment: Do you believe it is making your code any more readable or efficient? No it is not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ternary operators and Return in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566413/ternary-operators-and-return-in-c) Short answer: You can't, however you can return a tenary expression. Anyway, two nested tenary operators, comma operators...You probably think this is cool but it really isn't. Write clean code, that's cool code.

Comment: *exit* does not return a value (is *void*) -> you cannot use it at you do

Comment: Not recommending, this is valid: `int cond = 1; cond ? (void)puts("hello") : exit(1);` (make both expressions for true and false `void`)

Comment: Thank you! My goal is to make the code cleaner (the ternary operator might make it worse, you are right @EugeneSh., @dtell). Is there any other way to make this code better?

Comment: a derived version of your code being syntactically correct is : `return (argc != 2) ? (printf("Error X\n"), exit(1), 10) : ((NULL == file) ? (printf("Cannot open file!\n"), exit(1), 10) : 0);` where the two 100 can be any other int, but as you can see that is just non readable. *return* cannot be used inside the ternary if. Out of that can I suppose *file* is set *after* checking *argc* and before checking it values NULL so a piece of code is missing ?

Comment: [Here's something between a dumb trick and a useful pattern](https://repl.it/repls/ElementaryFirsthandSdk). Not sure I would use it in real code. I don't personally see anything wrong with the `if`s and `exit`s.

Comment: The first version of your code is good. It's simple and readable. OTOH it's unclear where `file` comes from. You should show more code, then we can tell you more.

Comment: @trentcl wow, that reads like bash.

Comment: @dtell I would also accept "wow, that reads like Perl".

Comment: The code you added with the edit is fine. Only `checkFile` is pretty pointless, you open the file and then you quit the function without doing anything with `file` and eventually leaking the file handle.

Comment: @Jabberwocky How can I fix that issue?

Comment: @trentcl Thank you. I like it. Although it might be not as readable. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to use an exit/return statement in ternary operator?

You cannot.  The second and third operands of a ternary operator must be expressions, and a `return` *statement* is not an expression (see [Ternary operators and Return in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3566413/2402272)).  It is, however, allowed for the two to both be void expressions, such as `exit(1)`, in which case the result of the operation is also a void expression.

Additionally, with respect to your specific code, the comma operator (`,`) has the lowest precedence of all C operators.  Therefore, if you intend to use a comma expression as an operand in any other operation, then you need to parenthesize it.

> I wanted to formulate these two if statements in a shorter way:

Why?  Mere conciseness or brevity is not a useful objective.  If it makes your code hard for a human to read and understand, then making your code shorter is a liability.

But if you mean that you want to express the same thing more *simply*, more *clearly*, and / or less *redundantly*, then that can lead you toward forms that also happen to be shorter.  For example, you can encapsulate the logic in a function or macro.  Personally I often supply a macro that looks something like this:

```
#define ERROR_IF_NZ(cond, message) do { \
    if (cond) { \
        fputs(message, stderr); \
        exit(1); \
    } \
} while (0)
```

Using that, your code could look like this:

```
ERROR_IF_NZ(argc != 2, "Error X\n");
ERROR_IF_NZ(NULL == file, "Cannot open file!\n");
```

Adjust the macro name so that it makes the most sense to you, and look!  It is not only clearer than the original code, but shorter, too, even if you count the length of the macro definition.

### Update

Edits to the question have pretty much mooted this answer.  If you already have functions that serve the the same role that a macro such as described here would do, then just call them.  There is no redeeming value in replacing the functions and the calls to them with a ternary expression, nor is it worth any effort to convert the functions you have into macros.  Certainly, reducing source code size is not an reasonable motivation for such changes.

Comment: Why did you use a macro? A function is perfectly capable of expressing this repetition

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica, whoever said that macros must be reserved for circumstances that cannot be addressed by functions?  I suppose I use a macro because I have somewhat old-school habits.  It is a style choice.

Comment: I've heard plenty of people say that, actually. With very good justification: 1) (Correct) Macros require the `do { } while (0)` and `\\` nonsense, 2) Macros defeat code highlighting in some editors and most sites (SO, GitHub, etc), 3) it's performance-wise unnecessary (the optimizer can both inline functions and errr "outline" macros, so it doesn't really do anything)

Comment: Hi @JohnBollinger, I like the approach of your answer. However I'm not as experienced, so it would help me much if you could explain me how your macro works in a little more detail. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica, sorry, I misspoke.  I meant to say, "whoever whose opinion I care about said [...]".  I'm making no assertions about performance or inlining, and I see no reason to categorize the other points you raise as anything other than style considerations.  As I said, where I use macros such as the one presented, it is a style choice.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That was an impressively unpleasant way to say that.

Comment: Well, I suppose I do not like having my perfectly valid style choices criticized.  I did not mean it personally, except inasmuch as if you count yourself as a person who says that macros should never be used where a function can serve, then indeed, that does not sway my dissenting opinion.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thank you for your update. I'm still enjoying your macro solution. Would it be possible to explain the syntax of the macro a little further? That would make it possible for me to accept your answer as solving the problem in the best way. Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry, @NilsK, but I don't quite understand what details you want me to explain.  Uses of a macro are expanded to the `#define`d replacement text.  For function-like macros such as this, the macro arguments are also filled in in place of the corresponding placeholders. You can perform such a replacement by hand to see the result.

Answer (score 2):

The code you added with the edit is readable and more or less fine, you don't need to obfuscate it with ternary operator tricks.

Only `checkFile` is pretty pointless, you open the file and then you quit the function without doing anything with file and eventually leaking the file handle.

You probably want this pattern:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    checkCommandLineArguments(argc, &argv[1]);
    FILE *file = checkFile(&argv[1]);

    // do stuff with file

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}

FILE *checkFile(char *argv[])
{
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (NULL == file)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return file;
}
```